# Average of neighbouring pairs 'interpolation'

Tags: matlab, vector, replace

I have two vectors, for example

```
A = [1,   3,   6,   7]
B = [2.0, 5.1, 2.2, 1]
```

I want to create a vector `C` and `C1` so it would create the missing elements and assign to each of them the ***average*** of the corresponding surrounding elements in `B`.

```
C  = [1,   2,    3,   4,    5,    6,   7]
C1 = [2.0, 3.55, 5.1, 3.65, 3.65, 2.2, 1]
```

What is the best way to that?

Comment: You really should show that you've tried to solve it yourself by posting some code...

Comment: You should check the `interp1` function. To create the interpolation vector, you might be able to use: `C = min(A):max(A)`

Comment: @sebastian to use `interp1` OP would first need to create a `Ci` like `[1,2,3,4.5,4.5,6,7]` which is non-trivial

Comment: @Dan: Hm. Can't see where your `Ci` is coming from. `A`, `B` and `C` is all that's needed to produce `C1` using `interp1`.

Comment: @sebastian OP does not want interpolation but wants to insert the average value of each neighbouring pair. Hence the `3.65` repeated in the final `C1`. Try use `interp1` to produce `C1`.

Comment: @Dan, ah, I see. I missed the repeated `3.65` for the elements 4 and 5...

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `interp1` you would need

```
Ci = [1, 2, 3, 4.5, 4.5, 6, 7]
```

and then

```
C1 = interp1(A,B,Ci)
```

However generating that `Ci` is about as difficult as generating `C1`. I think in this case your best bet is to loop:

```
%// Assuming A is sorted
C = min(A):max(A);
C1 = zeros(size(C));
Acounter = 1;
for ii = 1:numel(C)
    if C(ii)==A(Acounter)
        C1(ii) = B(Acounter);
        Acounter = Acounter + 1;
    else
        C1(ii) = (B(Acounter) + B(Acounter-1))/2;
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi Dan! Thanks for your respond, it's working just the way i need it. I really didn't have any ideas earlier otherwise i would post smth.

Comment: @LatahLena no problem, if this has worked, please mark it as solved.